# Using Latex equations in R

Tags: r, latex

So I am using R Markdown for my assignment, and whenever I use latex equation using "[]", the equatio goes to the center of the page with a new line. Is there a way to write my writing and equations on the same line? and not being centered?

T

Comment: Try using single dollars signs, like `$\beta = 0$`.

Comment: @Lyngbakr got it! Thank you!